# How to not show characters being entered from a keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ada

As part of a semester long class project, we are programming a model train system. Part of this is a monitor interface for viewing the current status, and keyboard inputs for system commands. When getting the keyboard inputs, we are not supposed to display them.

Is there a way to disable displaying inputs to the screen or how would I get those from the keyboard stream?

Currently using Ada.Text_IO package and have tested with both Get and Get_Immediate.

Additional

We are not developing for a linux system. We are developing for MaRTE_OS on what can basically be called a stand-alone terminal. This system is connected to dozens of hardware boards most of which I haven't seen or could even tell you what they are there for.

As for the monitor, the screen will be completely filled with output updated frequently (part of the system I have it refreshing info about 0.05 sec). There is no room to attempt to try to not display the information and then shift back up a line (also nothing really gets printed a line at a time, the display class prints what it needs to straight to a col,row on the screen).

The input does not need to be reviewed by the user entering it as the system is just supposed to read it and generate a command to be processed (also it has an ERROR command that is there for bad inputs and just does nothing but allow the system to circle back to a waiting state).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Ada, but you can run the following commands on unix systems:
`stty -echo` and `stty -noecho`. They toggle the echo mode. I use this in many different languages and it always works.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd verify the requirement. I can see not repeating the command, but canceling echo seems a little user-hostile. Alternatively, if your console supports [VT100 ANSI Escape Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php), you could use one of the `clear line` codes.

Answer (score 2):

Building on trashgods suggestion :

```
with Ada.Text_Io;
with Ada.Characters.Latin_1;

procedure Bsmain is
   Achar : Character := ' ';
   Escape: Character renames Ada.Characters.Latin_1.ESC;
begin
   Ada.Text_Io.Put (Escape & "[8m"); -- invisible text mode
   while Achar /= 'q' loop -- q=quit
      Ada.Text_Io.Get (Achar);
      Ada.Text_Io.Put (Escape & "[1A"); -- move cursor back up a line
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_Io.Put (Escape & "[m"); -- restore back to normal text mode
end Bsmain;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access required you can set up a keyboard interrupt then you could "head them off at the pass."

http://www.iuma.ulpgc.es/users/jmiranda/gnat-rts/node33.htm